# JAXRS tries to call Interface instead of Implementation

Tags: rest, jax-rs

I got a JAXRS application. I have an Interface class (SomeResource) (where i put most of my annotations) and an implementation of this interface (SomeService).

I have registered the SomeService.class in the overriden JaxRSApplication method .getClasses();

All my other services/resources are implemented in the same way, but whenever i try to call this one service (SomeService), i get the following exception:

"Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.InvokeMethodHandler can not access a member of class package.api.SomeResource with modifiers "public abstract""

As you can see, for some reason, this one Service tries to call the Resource(Interface) instead of the the Service class with the actual implementation.

Anyone got an idea how to resolve this? (Real classnames hidden because of security).

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to declare the implementation class of the service (SomeService.class) with its full qualified classname and not the interface within your rest service configurationen of your application.

The way you have to do that depends on the implementing framework.

Have a look here:

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-configuration.html